# Does Kubernetes cache docker-registry secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, aws-ecr

We are pulling images from a private ECR (AWS) running Kubernetes that ships with Docker for Mac (minikube). We have a secret called `aws-cred`. I created it using:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry aws-creds --docker-server=OUR-ACCOUNT.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com --docker-username=AWS --docker-password=SUPER_LONG_TOKEN --docker-email=foo@bar.com
```

together with this in my deployments:

```
"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"aws-creds"}]
```

SUPER_LONG_TOKEN I get from running:

```
aws ecr get-login --region eu-central-1 --profile default --no-include-email
```

Of course the token expires after a few hours and I tried to refresh the secret. First I deleted the secret:

```
kubectl delete secret aws-creds
```

Then basically repeated the steps above, fetching a fresh token. However I noticed, that I still cannot pull from our ECR getting a `AWS ECR: no basic auth credentials` error in minikube.

When I repeat the process, but I **rename** the secret, i.e. to `aws-creds-2`, everything works. I suspect there is some kind of caching in place. Indeed I verified this by using:

```
kubectl get secret aws-cred --output="jsonpath={.data.\.dockerconfigjson}" | base64 --decode
```

and I can see that the `password` value stays the same, even after deleting and re-creating the secret. This is a bit unintuitive to me, how should I update my secret instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this solution for a few months without issues. It runs inside your cluster and keeps your secret refreshed.  https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/registry-creds